# Remove name-value pair from the object giving only the value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object with name-value pairs. How can I target and remove specific name-value pair if all I have is the value?

```
{
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'boo',
  3: 'goo',
  4: 'moo'
}
```

Please note this is important - all i have is 'boo', and possibility is that this value will change the number in the future. I need to target the exact string.

Comment: Are values guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes____________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've made it a bit simpler:

```
const newObj = map(myObj, value => value !== valueToRemove)
```

So there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was tagged with lodash, then you might want to use its [`omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#omitBy) function, that removes a certain property of an object based on the return value of its predicate callback function.

```
const result = _.omitBy(object, v => v === 'foo');
```

```js
const object = {
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'boo',
  3: 'goo',
  4: 'moo'
};

const result = _.omitBy(object, v => v === 'foo');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional, immutable solution:

```
const cleanObj = (obj, val) => 
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value !== val)
    .reduce((o, [k, v]) => ({ ...o, [k]: v }), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object) and a `for`.

If you want to delete multiple properties with that value, remove the `return obj;` from inside the for.

```js
var valueToRemove = 'boo';
var myObj = {
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'boo',
  3: 'goo',
  4: 'moo'
};

console.log(myObj);
removePropertyByValue(myObj, valueToRemove)
console.log(myObj);

function removePropertyByValue(obj, value) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj[prop] == value) {
      delete obj[prop];
      return obj;
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object, and build a new object from the entries that don't have the specified value:

```js
const obj = {
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'boo',
  3: 'goo',
  4: 'moo'
}

const omitKeyByValue = (val) => {
  const r = {};
  
  for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(obj[k] !== val) r[k] = v;
  }

  return r;
};


console.log(omitKeyByValue('boo'));
```